# Convert nested list into data frame wide format

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I would like to convert a (nested?) list into a specific kind of wide format data frame. At first I show what the list data looks like at the moment. At the bottom of the post I show how I want the data frame to look like.

The structure of the list `str(zF_agg2)` looks like this

```
List of 4
 $ 252: Named num [1:48] 0.1491 0.1209 -0.0786 -0.1141 -0.0642 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:48] "VA01_F0finEnv_sma" "VA01_F0final_sma" "VA01_jitterLocal_sma" "VA01_shimmerLocal_sma" ...
 $ 306: Named num [1:24] -0.265 -0.217 0.151 0.21 0.114 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:24] "VA01_F0finEnv_sma" "VA01_F0final_sma" "VA01_jitterLocal_sma" "VA01_shimmerLocal_sma" ...
 $ 371: Named num [1:48] 0.1491 0.1209 -0.0786 -0.1141 -0.0642 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:48] "VA01_F0finEnv_sma" "VA01_F0final_sma" "VA01_jitterLocal_sma" "VA01_shimmerLocal_sma" ...
 $ 389: Named num [1:24] 1.59e-18 -9.46e-17 -2.37e-17 2.85e-17 -9.63e-17 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:24] "VA03_F0finEnv_sma" "VA03_F0final_sma" "VA03_jitterLocal_sma" "VA03_shimmerLocal_sma" ...
```

The list looks like this

```
$`252`
     VA01_F0finEnv_sma       VA01_F0final_sma   VA01_jitterLocal_sma  VA01_shimmerLocal_sma 
          1.490953e-01           1.209293e-01          -7.857455e-02          -1.141023e-01 
      VA01_mfcc_sma.0.       VA01_mfcc_sma.1.       VA01_mfcc_sma.2.       VA01_mfcc_sma.3. 
         -6.422870e-02          -3.020678e-02          -2.085494e-01          -1.920209e-01 
      VA01_mfcc_sma.4.       VA01_mfcc_sma.5.       VA01_mfcc_sma.6.       VA01_mfcc_sma.7. 
         -3.705184e-02          -9.375184e-02           7.214606e-02          -1.432561e-01 
      VA01_mfcc_sma.8.       VA01_mfcc_sma.9.      VA01_mfcc_sma.10.      VA01_mfcc_sma.11. 
         -7.943067e-02          -2.449599e-01          -7.746337e-02           7.970790e-03 
     VA01_mfcc_sma.12.      VA01_mfcc_sma.13.      VA01_mfcc_sma.14.   VA01_F0finEnv_sma SD 
         -2.187090e-01          -2.304651e-01          -1.662806e-01           9.294909e-01 
   VA01_F0final_sma SD   VA01_F0finEnv_sma RG    VA01_F0final_sma RG VA01_pcm_intensity_sma 
          8.839473e-01           5.717988e+00           5.333469e+00           1.317796e-01 
     VB01_F0finEnv_sma       VB01_F0final_sma   VB01_jitterLocal_sma  VB01_shimmerLocal_sma 
          1.851272e-16          -5.009943e-17          -2.348591e-17          -2.604552e-17 
      VB01_mfcc_sma.0.       VB01_mfcc_sma.1.       VB01_mfcc_sma.2.       VB01_mfcc_sma.3. 
         -2.391990e-17          -3.890029e-17          -2.785709e-17           2.683726e-17 
      VB01_mfcc_sma.4.       VB01_mfcc_sma.5.       VB01_mfcc_sma.6.       VB01_mfcc_sma.7. 
         -2.083230e-17           5.737901e-18          -2.277669e-17           3.112273e-17 
      VB01_mfcc_sma.8.       VB01_mfcc_sma.9.      VB01_mfcc_sma.10.      VB01_mfcc_sma.11. 
         -2.453523e-18          -5.662469e-17           2.266112e-17           1.361854e-18 
     VB01_mfcc_sma.12.      VB01_mfcc_sma.13.      VB01_mfcc_sma.14.      VB01_F0finEnv_sma 
          1.131963e-17          -4.091183e-17           8.561561e-18           1.000000e+00 
      VB01_F0final_sma      VB01_F0finEnv_sma       VB01_F0final_sma VB01_pcm_intensity_sma 
          1.000000e+00           1.124750e+01           1.369369e+01          -3.446556e-17 

$`306`
     VA01_F0finEnv_sma       VA01_F0final_sma   VA01_jitterLocal_sma  VA01_shimmerLocal_sma 
           -0.26540630            -0.21720761             0.15086035             0.21046540 
      VA01_mfcc_sma.0.       VA01_mfcc_sma.1.       VA01_mfcc_sma.2.       VA01_mfcc_sma.3. 
            0.11434077             0.05377450             0.37126233             0.34183814 
      VA01_mfcc_sma.4.       VA01_mfcc_sma.5.       VA01_mfcc_sma.6.       VA01_mfcc_sma.7. 
            0.06596016             0.16689824            -0.12843535             0.25502638 
      VA01_mfcc_sma.8.       VA01_mfcc_sma.9.      VA01_mfcc_sma.10.      VA01_mfcc_sma.11. 
            0.14140350             0.43608087             0.13790130            -0.01418970 
     VA01_mfcc_sma.12.      VA01_mfcc_sma.13.      VA01_mfcc_sma.14.      VA01_F0finEnv_sma 
            0.38934865             0.41027690             0.29601484             1.06416828 
      VA01_F0final_sma      VA01_F0finEnv_sma       VA01_F0final_sma VA01_pcm_intensity_sma 
            1.14875290             5.53095033             5.59523999             0.13177964 

$`371`
     VA01_F0finEnv_sma       VA01_F0final_sma   VA01_jitterLocal_sma  VA01_shimmerLocal_sma 
          1.490953e-01           1.209293e-01          -7.857455e-02          -1.141023e-01 
      VA01_mfcc_sma.0.       VA01_mfcc_sma.1.       VA01_mfcc_sma.2.       VA01_mfcc_sma.3. 
         -6.422870e-02          -3.020678e-02          -2.085494e-01          -1.920209e-01 
      VA01_mfcc_sma.4.       VA01_mfcc_sma.5.       VA01_mfcc_sma.6.       VA01_mfcc_sma.7. 
         -3.705184e-02          -9.375184e-02           7.214606e-02          -1.432561e-01 
      VA01_mfcc_sma.8.       VA01_mfcc_sma.9.      VA01_mfcc_sma.10.      VA01_mfcc_sma.11. 
         -7.943067e-02          -2.449599e-01          -7.746337e-02           7.970790e-03 
     VA01_mfcc_sma.12.      VA01_mfcc_sma.13.      VA01_mfcc_sma.14.      VA01_F0finEnv_sma 
         -2.187090e-01          -2.304651e-01          -1.662806e-01           9.294909e-01 
      VA01_F0final_sma      VA01_F0finEnv_sma       VA01_F0final_sma VA01_pcm_intensity_sma 
          8.839473e-01           5.717988e+00           5.333469e+00          -2.961325e-01 
     VA02_F0finEnv_sma       VA02_F0final_sma   VA02_jitterLocal_sma  VA02_shimmerLocal_sma 
          1.851272e-16          -5.009943e-17          -2.348591e-17          -2.604552e-17 
      VA02_mfcc_sma.0.       VA02_mfcc_sma.1.       VA02_mfcc_sma.2.       VA02_mfcc_sma.3. 
         -2.391990e-17          -3.890029e-17          -2.785709e-17           2.683726e-17 
      VA02_mfcc_sma.4.       VA02_mfcc_sma.5.       VA02_mfcc_sma.6.       VA02_mfcc_sma.7. 
         -2.083230e-17           5.737901e-18          -2.277669e-17           3.112273e-17 
      VA02_mfcc_sma.8.       VA02_mfcc_sma.9.      VA02_mfcc_sma.10.      VA02_mfcc_sma.11. 
         -2.453523e-18          -5.662469e-17           2.266112e-17           1.361854e-18 
     VA02_mfcc_sma.12.      VA02_mfcc_sma.13.      VA02_mfcc_sma.14.      VA02_F0finEnv_sma 
          1.131963e-17          -4.091183e-17           8.561561e-18           1.000000e+00 
      VA02_F0final_sma      VA02_F0finEnv_sma       VA02_F0final_sma VA02_pcm_intensity_sma 
          1.000000e+00           1.124750e+01           1.369369e+01          -6.365529e-16 

$`389`
     VA03_F0finEnv_sma       VA03_F0final_sma   VA03_jitterLocal_sma  VA03_shimmerLocal_sma 
          1.586292e-18          -9.464618e-17          -2.369378e-17           2.853813e-17 
      VA03_mfcc_sma.0.       VA03_mfcc_sma.1.       VA03_mfcc_sma.2.       VA03_mfcc_sma.3. 
         -9.629405e-17          -5.495508e-17          -2.202477e-17          -4.454892e-17 
      VA03_mfcc_sma.4.       VA03_mfcc_sma.5.       VA03_mfcc_sma.6.       VA03_mfcc_sma.7. 
         -7.952470e-17          -1.056807e-17          -6.211858e-17           4.154178e-18 
      VA03_mfcc_sma.8.       VA03_mfcc_sma.9.      VA03_mfcc_sma.10.      VA03_mfcc_sma.11. 
         -8.151347e-18           1.995314e-18           3.121848e-17           2.181543e-17 
     VA03_mfcc_sma.12.      VA03_mfcc_sma.13.      VA03_mfcc_sma.14.      VA03_F0finEnv_sma 
          8.159633e-17           6.164483e-19           2.416510e-17           1.000000e+00 
      VA03_F0final_sma      VA03_F0finEnv_sma       VA03_F0final_sma VA03_pcm_intensity_sma 
          1.000000e+00           3.918357e+00           7.132235e+00          -3.446556e-17
```

This is what the list looks like displayed with `dput(zF_agg2)`:

```
list(`252` = c(VA01_F0finEnv_sma = 0.149095349677244, VA01_F0final_sma = 0.120929343088889, 
VA01_jitterLocal_sma = -0.0785745451433892, VA01_shimmerLocal_sma = -0.114102345203172, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.0. = -0.0642286999362642, VA01_mfcc_sma.1. = -0.030206778340382, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.2. = -0.208549388306997, VA01_mfcc_sma.3. = -0.192020923835602, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.4. = -0.0370518353007777, VA01_mfcc_sma.5. = -0.093751840248999, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.6. = 0.0721460591859715, VA01_mfcc_sma.7. = -0.143256107040908, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.8. = -0.0794306655354017, VA01_mfcc_sma.9. = -0.244959943019604, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.10. = -0.0774633729052873, VA01_mfcc_sma.11. = 0.00797079006761165, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.12. = -0.218709025578709, VA01_mfcc_sma.13. = -0.230465062187873, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.14. = -0.166280574763084, `VA01_F0finEnv_sma SD` = 0.929490898547702, 
`VA01_F0final_sma SD` = 0.88394728516363, `VA01_F0finEnv_sma RG` = 5.71798783504483, 
`VA01_F0final_sma RG` = 5.33346937206177, VA01_pcm_intensity_sma = 0.131779638620608, 
VB01_F0finEnv_sma = 1.85127192814681e-16, VB01_F0final_sma = -5.00994289546507e-17, 
VB01_jitterLocal_sma = -2.34859079707077e-17, VB01_shimmerLocal_sma = -2.60455164544764e-17, 
VB01_mfcc_sma.0. = -2.39198962485355e-17, VB01_mfcc_sma.1. = -3.89002856985193e-17, 
VB01_mfcc_sma.2. = -2.78570899311261e-17, VB01_mfcc_sma.3. = 2.68372615000544e-17, 
VB01_mfcc_sma.4. = -2.08322992987213e-17, VB01_mfcc_sma.5. = 5.73790146364059e-18, 
VB01_mfcc_sma.6. = -2.27766888801672e-17, VB01_mfcc_sma.7. = 3.11227273727354e-17, 
VB01_mfcc_sma.8. = -2.45352291763184e-18, VB01_mfcc_sma.9. = -5.66246851843269e-17, 
VB01_mfcc_sma.10. = 2.26611187363704e-17, VB01_mfcc_sma.11. = 1.36185358636217e-18, 
VB01_mfcc_sma.12. = 1.13196270572855e-17, VB01_mfcc_sma.13. = -4.09118309040634e-17, 
VB01_mfcc_sma.14. = 8.56156119316215e-18, VB01_F0finEnv_sma = 1, 
VB01_F0final_sma = 1, VB01_F0finEnv_sma = 11.2475000713838, VB01_F0final_sma = 13.6936948927086, 
VB01_pcm_intensity_sma = -3.4465563242102e-17), `306` = c(VA01_F0finEnv_sma = -0.265406298807794, 
VA01_F0final_sma = -0.217207612472567, VA01_jitterLocal_sma = 0.150860347120316, 
VA01_shimmerLocal_sma = 0.210465396713397, VA01_mfcc_sma.0. = 0.114340766331976, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.1. = 0.0537744993637855, VA01_mfcc_sma.2. = 0.371262331337075, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.3. = 0.341838144083938, VA01_mfcc_sma.4. = 0.065960158721897, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.5. = 0.166898244394498, VA01_mfcc_sma.6. = -0.128435352160981, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.7. = 0.255026383486623, VA01_mfcc_sma.8. = 0.141403503053762, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.9. = 0.436080874021934, VA01_mfcc_sma.10. = 0.137901303147026, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.11. = -0.0141897040654165, VA01_mfcc_sma.12. = 0.389348649641122, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.13. = 0.41027689879224, VA01_mfcc_sma.14. = 0.296014840147772, 
VA01_F0finEnv_sma = 1.06416827571567, VA01_F0final_sma = 1.14875289621226, 
VA01_F0finEnv_sma = 5.53095033394156, VA01_F0final_sma = 5.59523999359499, 
VA01_pcm_intensity_sma = 0.131779638620608), `371` = c(VA01_F0finEnv_sma = 0.149095349677244, 
VA01_F0final_sma = 0.120929343088889, VA01_jitterLocal_sma = -0.0785745451433892, 
VA01_shimmerLocal_sma = -0.114102345203172, VA01_mfcc_sma.0. = -0.0642286999362642, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.1. = -0.030206778340382, VA01_mfcc_sma.2. = -0.208549388306997, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.3. = -0.192020923835602, VA01_mfcc_sma.4. = -0.0370518353007777, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.5. = -0.093751840248999, VA01_mfcc_sma.6. = 0.0721460591859715, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.7. = -0.143256107040908, VA01_mfcc_sma.8. = -0.0794306655354017, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.9. = -0.244959943019604, VA01_mfcc_sma.10. = -0.0774633729052873, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.11. = 0.00797079006761165, VA01_mfcc_sma.12. = -0.218709025578709, 
VA01_mfcc_sma.13. = -0.230465062187873, VA01_mfcc_sma.14. = -0.166280574763084, 
VA01_F0finEnv_sma = 0.929490898547702, VA01_F0final_sma = 0.88394728516363, 
VA01_F0finEnv_sma = 5.71798783504483, VA01_F0final_sma = 5.33346937206177, 
VA01_pcm_intensity_sma = -0.296132477275194, VA02_F0finEnv_sma = 1.85127192814681e-16, 
VA02_F0final_sma = -5.00994289546507e-17, VA02_jitterLocal_sma = -2.34859079707077e-17, 
VA02_shimmerLocal_sma = -2.60455164544764e-17, VA02_mfcc_sma.0. = -2.39198962485355e-17, 
VA02_mfcc_sma.1. = -3.89002856985193e-17, VA02_mfcc_sma.2. = -2.78570899311261e-17, 
VA02_mfcc_sma.3. = 2.68372615000544e-17, VA02_mfcc_sma.4. = -2.08322992987213e-17, 
VA02_mfcc_sma.5. = 5.73790146364059e-18, VA02_mfcc_sma.6. = -2.27766888801672e-17, 
VA02_mfcc_sma.7. = 3.11227273727354e-17, VA02_mfcc_sma.8. = -2.45352291763184e-18, 
VA02_mfcc_sma.9. = -5.66246851843269e-17, VA02_mfcc_sma.10. = 2.26611187363704e-17, 
VA02_mfcc_sma.11. = 1.36185358636217e-18, VA02_mfcc_sma.12. = 1.13196270572855e-17, 
VA02_mfcc_sma.13. = -4.09118309040634e-17, VA02_mfcc_sma.14. = 8.56156119316215e-18, 
VA02_F0finEnv_sma = 1, VA02_F0final_sma = 1, VA02_F0finEnv_sma = 11.2475000713838, 
VA02_F0final_sma = 13.6936948927086, VA02_pcm_intensity_sma = -6.36552851373548e-16
), `389` = c(VA03_F0finEnv_sma = 1.58629187875084e-18, VA03_F0final_sma = -9.46461808448016e-17, 
VA03_jitterLocal_sma = -2.36937840621222e-17, VA03_shimmerLocal_sma = 2.85381254827705e-17, 
VA03_mfcc_sma.0. = -9.6294053113996e-17, VA03_mfcc_sma.1. = -5.49550802238737e-17, 
VA03_mfcc_sma.2. = -2.20247732336464e-17, VA03_mfcc_sma.3. = -4.454892003863e-17, 
VA03_mfcc_sma.4. = -7.9524696067784e-17, VA03_mfcc_sma.5. = -1.05680749785702e-17, 
VA03_mfcc_sma.6. = -6.21185832013518e-17, VA03_mfcc_sma.7. = 4.15417752575213e-18, 
VA03_mfcc_sma.8. = -8.15134676706638e-18, VA03_mfcc_sma.9. = 1.99531361473134e-18, 
VA03_mfcc_sma.10. = 3.1218480555731e-17, VA03_mfcc_sma.11. = 2.1815428854396e-17, 
VA03_mfcc_sma.12. = 8.15963331541171e-17, VA03_mfcc_sma.13. = 6.16448325097666e-19, 
VA03_mfcc_sma.14. = 2.41651014444211e-17, VA03_F0finEnv_sma = 1, 
VA03_F0final_sma = 1, VA03_F0finEnv_sma = 3.91835747651944, VA03_F0final_sma = 7.13223541696321, 
VA03_pcm_intensity_sma = -3.4465563242102e-17))
```

I would like a data frame that has an ID column, which holds the titles for the sub-lists (252, 306, 371, ...) and columns for the content inside the sublists. The columns for the content inside the sublists should keep their titles (VA01_F0finEnv_sma, ...). Those shared columns between sublists should be combined: Like 252 and 306 share the VA01_F0finEnv_sma named column. But 389 has columns starting with VA03 which the others dont have.

This is what the data is supposed to LOOK like:

| ID | VA01_F0finEnv | VA01_F0final | VA01_jitterLocal_sma | ... | VA03_pcm_intens. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 252 | 1.490953e-01 | 1.209293e-01 | -7.857455e-02 | ... | NA |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 389 | NA | NA | NA | ... | -3.446556e-17 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so currently your list contains a bunch of named vectors, which you need to first convert to lists, then to data frames (I assigned the sample data you supplied to `df`).

This uses the package, `plyr`.

```
df_list <- lapply(df, function(x) as.data.frame(as.list(x)))
```

This should convert each element in your list to a (sub) list then a data frame.

Then you can bind each of these lists with a new column, id, using the name of said list. After that, `bind.fill` will bind the rows of the data frames in your list, while filling in non-intersecting columns.

```
do.call(rbind.fill, unname(Map(cbind, id = names(df_list), df_list)))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use transpose each element of the list, convert to `data.table`, and `rbindlist()`, using the `fill=T` argument to allow columns names to differ:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(zF_agg2, \(i) as.data.table(t(i))), fill=T)
```